# Why can't OpenGL display this model when loaded from OBJ?

Tags: c++11, opengl

My entire project can be found at http://github.com/jep-dev/FOGL. It expects a Linux environment and the requirements found in the readme.

I have written a naive Wavefront OBJ loader and attempted to draw the results using OpenGL. I also created a mesh which successfully displays as a sphere in the center of the screen. I can serialize the mesh as an OBJ and load it successfully (see test/src/model.cpp) - however the loaded OBJ will not display. I can't think of what else to troubleshoot but the method I use to display the OBJ, except this method is almost identical to the way I display the mesh.

Displaying the mesh:

```
using namespace Model;
mesh_t mesh(150, 150,
[](float s, float t, std::vector<float> &vertices) {
    using namespace Math;
    auto theta = s*M_PI*2, phi = t*M_PI;
    vertices.emplace_back(cos(theta)*sin(phi)); // X
    vertices.emplace_back(sin(theta)*sin(phi)); // Y
    vertices.emplace_back(cos(phi));            // Z
});

glGenBuffers(1, &viewer.ids[view::e_id_vbuf]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, viewer.ids[view::e_id_vbuf]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertices.size() * sizeof(float),
    (void*) &mesh.vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &viewer.ids[view::e_id_fbuf]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    viewer.ids[view::e_id_fbuf]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.faces.size() * sizeof(int),
    (void*) &mesh.faces[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
viewer.nTriangles = mesh.faces.size()/3;
```

Displaying the OBJ:

```
using namespace Model;
        obj_t object;
        auto status = obj_t::load(this -> mpath, object);
        if(status != obj_t::e_ok) {
            errors.push_back("The model failed to load.");
            return alive = false;
        }

        // TODO Use more than first range of each obj type
        if(object.v_beg.size() == 0) {
            errors.push_back("The loaded model does not contain vertices.");
            return alive = false;
        } else {
            auto v0 = object.v_beg[0], v1 = object.v_end[0];
            glGenBuffers(1, &viewer.ids[view::e_id_vbuf]);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, viewer.ids[view::e_id_vbuf]);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v1-v0,
                    (void*)(&object.floats[v0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }
        if(object.vn_beg.size() != 0) {
            auto vn0 = object.vn_beg[0], vn1 = object.vn_end[0];
            glGenBuffers(1, &viewer.ids[view::e_id_vnbuf]);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, viewer.ids[view::e_id_vnbuf]);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vn1-vn0)*sizeof(float),
                    (void*)(&object.floats[vn0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }
        glGenBuffers(1, &viewer.ids[view::e_id_fbuf]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                viewer.ids[view::e_id_fbuf]);
        int f0, f1;
        if(object.f0_beg.size() != 0) {
            f0 = object.f0_beg[0];
            f1 = object.f0_end[0];
        } else if(object.f1_beg.size() != 0) {
            f0 = object.f1_beg[0];
            f1 = object.f1_end[0];
        } else if(object.f2_beg.size() != 0) {
            f0 = object.f2_beg[0];
            f1 = object.f2_end[0];
        } else if(object.f3_beg.size() != 0) {
            f0 = object.f3_beg[0];
            f1 = object.f3_end[0];
        } else {
            errors.push_back("The loaded model does not contain faces.");
            return alive = false;
        }
        viewer.nTriangles = (f1-f0)/3;
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, viewer.nTriangles*sizeof(int),
                (void*)(&object.ints[f0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The extra code is for range extraction as OBJ files can contain non-contiguous data, however the model I'm using is share/sphere.obj, which is contiguous. The model does not contain normals, just like the mesh. I have also verified the range extraction method, this does not appear to be the problem. Again, everything I've tested suggests that my OBJ loading is correct and generates no errors, which just leaves the method I use to display it.

If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. As an aside, I would like to know how to credit those who help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: use (f1-f0)*sizeof(int) instead of nTriangles, which is divided by 3, and add sizeof(float) to the size of the vertices being passed in.